# What is the purity of a thermal state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, density-operator

Consider a thermal state for some Hamiltonian $H$ over a $D$-dimensional Hilbert space, defined by
$$
\rho_{\beta} := \frac{ e^{- \beta H} }{\mathrm{Tr}[ e^{- \beta H} ]} \ .
$$
I've seen statements that thermal states are maximally mixed. However, when I compute the purity of the above state, I find
$$
\mathrm{Tr}[\rho_{\beta}^2] = \frac{\mathrm{Tr}[ e^{- 2\beta H} ]}{\mathrm{Tr}[ e^{- \beta H} ]^2} \ .
$$
This does not seem to be equal to $1 / D$, which I always thought was the hallmark of a maximally mixed state.

Can something further be learned about the purity of $\rho_\beta$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thermal states are not maximally mixed. The parameter $\beta$ (inverse temperature) can be tuned to go from a pure state to a maximally mixed state. For example, consider $\beta \rightarrow{\infty}$ i.e. low temperature limit. In this case, $Z = Tr[e^{-\beta H}] \approx e^{-\beta E_{0}}$, where $E_{0}$ is the ground state energy. So, $\rho_{\beta} \approx |0\rangle\langle0|$ (Pure state).

On the other hand, if you take $\beta \rightarrow{0}$ i.e. high temperature limit, you have $\rho_{\beta} \approx \frac{1}{D}$ and so, $Tr[\rho_{\beta}^{2}]=\frac{1}{D}$.